# EtherCAT not found after full installation

Tags: linux, bash, debian, command

I have been trying for the past few days to get the EtherCAT working with LinuxCNC, but my lack of knowledge about the Linux environment does not allow me to even start the project. I have all the necessary hardware and have the Debian 10 version with rt kernel and LinuxCNC preinstalled. I followed the installation procedure shown here:

https://forum.linuxcnc.org/10-advanced-configuration/42048-notes-from-installation-of-ethercat-on-raspberry-pi-4

The installation completes with no errors but I get a `bash: ethercat: command not found` after i reboot and try to run `ethercat master`.

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Welcome, does `sudo which ethercat` give any result?

Comment: nope, nothing comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the `deb` package then install it as described here:  [sittner/ec-debianize](https://github.com/sittner/ec-debianize)

```
sudo apt install mercurial
```

Enable `mq`:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.hgrc
[extensions]
mq =
EOF
```

Clone the repo and build the package:

```
git clone https://github.com/sittner/ec-debianize.git
./get_source.sh
cd etherlabmaster
sudo dpkg-checkbuilddeps 
sudo dpkg-buildpackage
```

Then install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i ethercat_<version>_<arch>.deb
```

The `ethercat` service can be launched through:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ethercat start
```

Comment: Is there an actual binary `ethercat`? Just curious as I honestly found no references to it.

Comment: @Peregrino69 `hg` will clone the necessary files to build the debian package. See [get_source.sh](https://github.com/sittner/ec-debianize/blob/master/get_source.sh)

Comment: Yap, but I mean after installation, does it create the binary you can launch :-) I found a lot of things that utilize EtherCAT but nothing that actually says `type /bin/ethercat` or sth like that. Way too much stuff to read when you don't know where to start :-D

Comment: @Peregrino69 Of course the binary will be installed after executing the `dpkg` command :)

Comment: oki, then it's more than just a protocol - I can remove my first comment here :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 It is a service it can launched through `/etc/init.d/ethercat start`

Comment: Yap, that's what I i found and was referring to in my first comment to the OP. I didn't find anything that implies it can be started the way OP tried, just by executing a binary :-)